# multiple span calls of javascript value

Tags: javascript, html

In my header I have

```
    function addusr() {
        document.getElementById("usrout").innerHTML = document.getElementById("usrin").value;}
```

and in my text I have

```
code-bla bla bla<span id="usrout"></span> bla!! It works!
```

but if I try to call `<span id="usrout"></span>` again on the same page at a different location, none of the others appear.

Example:

```
    text <span id="usrout"></span> more text, code... another <span id="usrout"></span>...
...
..
...
another <span id="usrout"></span> ...
```

Only the first one appears, why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you call a html element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An ID needs to be unique. You might want to consider classes instead.

When you’ve assigned classes to the HTML elements, your JavaScript code may look like this:

```
function addusr () {
    var usrin = document.getElementById("usrin").value,
        usrout = document.getElementsByClassName("usrout");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(usrout, function (el) {
        el.innerHTML = usrin;
    });
}
```

**Explanation:**

Instead of `getElementById`, we’re using `getElementsByClassName` which returns an array of elements having that particular classname. Thus a loop is required to set the `innerHTML` property of each retrieved element.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using same `ID` in more than one element is `WRONG` and against `RFC`.

You should make it a `CLASS`, not `ID`, and then...

```
document.querySelector(".usrout").innerHTML = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Every single element needs a unique ID.

For example

```
<span id="usrout1"></span>
<span id="usrout2"></span>
```

Alternatively, you could use classes as mentioned already

```
<span class="green"></span>
<span class="green"></span>
```

Then use a CSS selector such as document.getElementByClass

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs must be unique, so `getElementById` will only ever return (at most) one element.

You need to use a different search, perhaps [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll), to get all the applicable elements. You can then loop through them, and set the necessary comment.

For example:

```js
function addusr() {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("usrin").value;

  var outputs = document.querySelectorAll("span.usrout");
  for (var i = 0; i < outputs.length; ++i) {
    outputs[i].textContent = inputValue;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="usrin" type="text" />
<button type="button" onclick="addusr();">Update</button>

<span class="usrout"></span>
<span class="usrout"></span>
<span class="usrout"></span>
<span class="usrout"></span>
<span class="usrout"></span>
<span class="usrout"></span>
```